# How can i remove the timezone offset from datetime in python

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am using delorean in my code.

http://delorean.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#truncation

```
now = Delorean(timezone=settings.TIME_ZONE).datetime

start = Delorean(datetime.combine(now.date(), rule.start_time),
                                               timezone=settings.TIME_ZONE).datetime
```

It prints like this

```
2014-12-05 05:15:00+11:00
```

In the data base it stores like this

```
2014-12-04 18:15:00+00`
```

because django stores in UTC in database

Now how can I get the datetime according to current time zone

I tried this

```
Delorean(obj.start_time, timezone=settings.TIME_ZONE).datetime
```

it displayed this

```
2014-12-04 19:00:00+00:00
```

even `obj.start_time` also prints

```
2014-12-04 19:00:00+00:00
```

how can i get this

```
2014-12-05 05:15:00+11:00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Django's utilities](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.timezone) for this.

```
from django.utils.timezone import localtime

localtime(obj.start_time)
```

That will convert it to a `datetime` in the current time zone (which is `TIME_ZONE` by default).

Comment: can i do all stuff with timezone. i don't understand why django recommmned to us `pytz`. what thing can't be done by django utils which can be done by `pytz`

Comment: @KKJOJ: Django will use `pytz` when it's available because it can do more accurate conversions than Python's built-in facilities. That's because, unlike Python, it contains a database of facts about timezones, which can be complicated. This is why Python is planning to integrate `pytz` in a future release: see [PEP 431](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0431/).