# How can I get the timezone aware date in django?

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

I am using delorean for datetime calculation in python django.

http://delorean.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

This is what I am using:

```
now = Delorean(timezone=settings.TIME_ZONE).datetime
todayDate = now.date()
```

But I get this warning:

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField start_time received a naive datetime (2014-12-09 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
```

I want to know how to make it aware.

I tried this as well:

```
todayDate = timezone.make_aware(now.date(), timezone=settings.TIME_ZONE)
```

then I get this:

```
AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'
```

Comment: Not sure how it works in `Delorean` but datetimes can be timezone aware, for dates the concept makes less sense.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It's not clear whether you're trying to end up with a `date` object or a `datetime` object, as Python doesn't have the concept of a "timezone aware date".

To get a `date` object corresponding to the current time in the current time zone, you'd use:

```
# All versions of Django
from django.utils.timezone import localtime, now
localtime(now()).date()

# Django 1.11 and higher
from django.utils.timezone import localdate
localdate()
```

That is: you're getting the current timezone-aware `datetime` in UTC; you're converting it to the local time zone (i.e. `TIME_ZONE`); and then taking the date from that.

If you want to get a `datetime` object corresponding to 00:00:00 on the current date in the current time zone, you'd use:

```
# All versions of Django
localtime(now()).replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

# Django 1.11 and higher
localtime().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

Based on this and [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308951/how-can-i-remove-the-timezone-offset-from-datetime-in-python), I think you're getting confused by the Delorean package. I suggest sticking with Django's and Python's datetime functionality.